# Svelte: How to import all stores from a file without listing them all?

Tags: javascript, svelte

Is it possible to import all exported stores from a file in a single line? Instead of listing them all like so:

```
    import { store1, store2, store3 } from './stores.js';
```

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
    import { * } from './stores.js';
```

or is there some other workaround?
If not, what is the recommended architecture to avoid the need for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if it satisfies your needs but you could export all stores in an object

```
//main.svelte
<script>
    import stores from './stores.js';
    let count_value, store1_v, store2_v;
    stores.count.subscribe(value => {
        count_value = value;
    });
    stores.store1.subscribe(value => {
        store1_v = value;
    });
    stores.store2.subscribe(value => {
        store2_v = value;
    });
</script>

<h1>The count is {count_value}</h1>
<h1>The count is {store1_v}</h1>
<h1>The count is {store2_v}</h1>
```

```
//stores.js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export const count = writable(0);
export const store1 = writable(4565465);
export const store2 = writable(345);

export default {
count,
store1,
store2,
}
```

Another option for stores would be

```js
//stores.js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export default {
count: writable(0),
store1: writable(4565465),
store2: writable(345),
}
```

Comment: Good enough! Thanks!